# Zend routing issues

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Im new to zend framework 2 and am trying to create an API using the skeleton application. All is going well apart from issues im having with routing. Ive looked through the answers to simular questions but i cant figure out what im doing wrong in the module.config file that is stopping my api from routing.

Heres my config :

```html
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

        // Segmented Routes
        'websites' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'routes'   => '/api/websites/[/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Websites',
                    'action'        => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // List of envokable classes.
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Websites' => 'Application\Controller\WebsitesController'            
        ),
    ),

    // Views
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies'               => array('ViewJsonStrategy'),
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),

    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!

The issue was caused by the controller not being able to handle url's with trailing /

Here is the working code :

```html
            'api' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'   => '/api/websites[/:id][/]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Websites',
                        'action'        => 'index'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Big thanks to JonaPkr for his help solving this issue.

Comment: Great, trailing slash is, in fact, samoething that i didn't think about. I posted some explain ;)

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect recommendation - Credit goes to JonaPkr

Answer (score 0):

Which routes are failing exactly ?
It seems your "websites" route is wrong, try replacing by the following:
**EDIT**

Get your param in controller like this

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('id')
```

Here the config

```
        // Segmented Routes
        'websites' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'   => '/api/websites[/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'        => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

**Ultime Edit**

Regarding the message you posted, first, it's great you solved your problem.
But i don't think you got the better syntax. First you need to understand how the "Route" is composed, let decompose it:

So in first part you got **"/api/websites"**:

This is the literal part of the route, this part is never changed and always be in your URL. Then we have segments.

A segment is composed of a colon followed by a alphanum string, like **:id** in your exemple. Brackets means that your segment is optional (and so we don't have defaults values (even if i don't know if defaults are mendatory when non optional segment is present)).

So you said that your problem was caused by a trailing "/", in fact this can be a problem that i didn't think about, i put another source code for you:

```
    // Segmented Routes
    'websites' => array(
        'type'    => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'   => '/api/websites[/:id][/]',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                'action'        => 'index'
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Finding a problem is great, understanding his errors is better.
Heppy that i have helped you ;)

Comment: Hi Jona, Thanks for the reply :) I've updated the code but no luck, still getting a 404 error. I've used the literal routes before without an issue, don't understand why the segmented ones aren't working.